# Undocumented in 13.9? ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return record Detail: final statement returns bigint instead of integer

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

The subject compilation error is no longer being thrown in 13.9. I couldn't find anything in the documentation stating that numeric data types are now getting automatically casted before they get returned. Can someone please confirm whether this is a new in 13.9?

I compiled a SQL function declared to return an INT, but the data type from the SELECT is a BIGINT:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test() RETURNS int
  AS $$ SELECT 1::bigint; $$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

**Version 12** ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hj_nBX-W)):
I receive the following error:
ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return record
Detail: Final statement returns bigint instead of integer at column 11.

**Version 13.9 and above** ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CB-r65Vj)):
No compiling ERROR.

Comment: @AlexRodriguez You should consider forcing your developers to use the same version of postgres for development as you are using for production. In a container, that shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @Bergi Working on it... Thx!!

Answer (score 2):

This was changed in v13 at [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=913bbd88dc6b85).  It did not make the release notes, but the documentation was changed accordingly, as reflected in changes made to
doc/src/sgml/xfunc.sgml.  Unless you were comparing the docs side by side between versions, you might not notice the change.